# SugerCRM / SuiteCRM: Error with preg_replace() and modifier "e" in Smarty 2.6.0 on PHP 5.5.3

Tags: php, preg-replace, smarty, sugarcrm, preg-replace-callback

The PHP Template Engine: Smarty 2.6.0 (/includes/Smarty) is using a deprecated modifier 'e' for preg_replace function call:

Block causing error: /include/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php @ line 262

```
/* replace special blocks by "{php}" */
$source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
. $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
. "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
. $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
. "'"
, $source_content);
```

if you try simply to upgrade Smarty to the current version 3.1.16, or the closest available version 2.6.28. it will not work.

Here comes solution:

So I applied substitute call recommanded by PHP reference. 
Change:  /include/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php @ line 262

```
/* replace special blocks by "{php}" */
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search, 
function($m) { 
    return "{php ".str_repeat("\n", substr_count($m[0], "\n"))."}";
},
$source_content);
```

I hope this will help someone else and save him few hours.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should allow for other Smarty delimiter tags to be used with your substitution:

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search,
                                        function($m) {
                                        return $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter)."php ".str_repeat("\n", substr_count($m[0], "\n")).$this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter);
                                        },
                                        $source_content);
```